# Get file name from Django Document object

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form which I am using to upload a file.
The code inside my views.py file is:

```
def upload(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()
            # Redirect to the document list after POST

            return HttpResponse("Success!")
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()  # A empty, unbound form

        # Load documents for the list page
        documents = Document.objects.all()

        # Render list page with the documents and the form
        return render_to_response(
             'upload.html',
             {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
             context_instance=RequestContext(request)
             )
```

How do I get to know the file name which is being created?
I am using Django v. 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python you can get that using name attribute.,.

```
newdoc = request.FILES['docfile']
newdoc.name # file name
```

Andv if you wish to see that in the template here is the code

```
{% for document in documents %}
{{ document.file.filename }}
{% endfor }}
```

In the model objects

```
newdoc = Document.objects.get(id=1)
newdoc.docfile.url # url of the file
newdoc.docfile.path # exact path
```

Comment: This is getting me the name of the original file. I want the name by which it is getting saved (if I'm adding multiple files, Django adds some more string to separate them) , more so, I want the whole path name.

Inside my models.py file, I have something like, 
 
`docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')`

I want the whole path name to be displayed.

Comment: I get this error, AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'url'